# std::process::Command executes without error but nothing happens

Tags: rust

I'm trying to `cd` into a directory that contains `steamcmd.exe` and run a command. When I run this code no error occurs and nothing actually happens.

```
use std::{process::Command};

let steamcmd_dir = String::from("C:/Users/user/Desktop/steamcmd");
let content = String::from("steamcmd +login anonymous");
let mut command = Command::new("cmd");

command.arg("/C");
command.arg("cd");
command.arg("/C");
command.arg(steamcmd_dir);
command.arg("/C");
command.arg(content);

command.output().unwrap();
```

Comment: That just means it successfully started `cmd` and ran it to the end (successfully or not) have you inspected the actual [`Output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Output.html) returned by `output()`?

Comment: You should also confirm `cmd /C cd /C C:/Users/user/Desktop/steamcmd /C "steamcmd +login anonymous"` does what you expect it to outside of Rust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Command::output()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output) documentation explains:

> Executes the command as a child process, waiting for it to finish and collecting all of its output.

SteamCMD works similarly to e.g a database CLI client in the sense that you can use it both interactively as well as for one-off commands using its command line flags. However the flags you supplied to SteamCMD makes it run in interactive mode and not exit at all, so you need to append `+quit` for SteamCMD to exit when it is finished, like so:

```
steamcmd +login anonymous +quit
```

You also don't necessarily need to go through `cmd` and `cd` to where SteamCMD is located, you can reference the executable directly if that's desirable to you:

```rust
let output = Command::new("C:/Users/user/Desktop/steamcmd/steamcmd.exe")
    .args(["+login", "anonymous", "+quit"])
    .output()
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: Thumbs up in particular for the advice to avoid unnecessary invoking `cmd.exe`

Comment: Well this is slightly different semantically though, namely it's another the working directory, I don't know `steamcmd` so don't know if that matters.

Comment: @cafce25 Good point! SteamCMD is normally used to install game server files or query information about a specific game, and typical usage looks like `steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir C:\servers\some_game +app_update xxxx validate +quit` If the `+force_install_dir` is omitted, CWD will be used.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs on `cmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd):

> To use multiple commands for `<string>`, separate them by the command separator `&&`.

So instead you can use something like this:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let steamcmd_dir = String::from("C:/Users/user/Desktop/steamcmd");
    let content = String::from("steamcmd +login anonymous");
    let mut command = Command::new("cmd")
        .arg("/C")
        .arg([format!("cd {}", steamcmd_dir), content].join("&&"));

    command.output().unwrap();
}
```

However you can also avoid using `cmd` alltogether by using [`std::env::set_current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.set_current_dir.html) to change the current processes working directory and then running `steamcwd` directly like in [Svenskunganka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75574806/442760):

```rust
fn main() {
    let steamcmd_dir = String::from("C:/Users/user/Desktop/steamcmd");
    std::env::set_current_dir(steamcmd_dir).unwrap();
    let mut command = Command::new("steamcmd")
        .args(["+login", "anonymous", "+quit"]);

    command.output().unwrap();
}
```